# Training dosen't progress for repeating sequences of 2bit x 12

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am testing simpleRNN model

My test data is super simple repeating triple 2bit * 12

`[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]`

```
for i in range(0,100):
    temp = [[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]
    line.extend(temp)
total = []
for j in range(0,500):
    total.append(line)
total = np.array(total)
print(total.shape) # (500, 300, 12)
```

It makes `(500, 300, 12)` numpy. All data is just repeating, So I expect training and prediction works perfectly.

However `val_loss` dosen't decrease and prediction doesn't effectively work.

```
Epoch 1/5
743/743 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1386 - val_loss: 0.1305
Epoch 2/5
743/743 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1305 - val_loss: 0.1294
Epoch 3/5
743/743 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1299 - val_loss: 0.1292
Epoch 4/5
743/743 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1300 - val_loss: 0.1291
Epoch 5/5
743/743 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1299 - val_loss: 0.1293
[[ 0.67032564 -0.0020391   0.3332582  -0.0095186   0.35370785  0.3042156
   0.00809216  0.7059332   0.00199411  0.30952734 -0.0021943   0.333712  ]]
tf.Tensor([[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]], shape=(1, 12), dtype=int32)
```

I expect result as smillar `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` though,,,,

I need to change somewhere or my code is wrong??

These are my whole cord.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNN
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def makeModel(input_len,n_in):
    n_hidden = 512
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden, input_shape=(input_len, n_in), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation="relu")) 
    model.add(Dense(n_in, activation="relu"))
    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
    model.summary()
    return model
 

line = []
    
for i in range(0,100):
    temp = [[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]
    line.extend(temp)
total = []
for j in range(0,500):
    total.append(line)
total = np.array(total)
print(total.shape) # (500, 300, 12)

chordIdList = total
n_in = 12 # dimention
input_len = 3 # length to use prediction.
model = makeModel(input_len,n_in)

input_=[]
target_=[]
for C in chordIdList:
    for i in range(0, len(C) - input_len):  
        input_.append( C[i:i+input_len] )  
        target_.append( C[i+input_len] )  
        
X = np.array(input_)
Y = np.array(target_).reshape((len(input_),1,n_in))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x, x_val,y, y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size=0.8, random_state=1)
print(x.shape) # (23760, 3, 12)
print(y.shape) # (23760, 1, 12)
print(x_val.shape) #(5940, 3, 12)
print(y_val.shape) # (5940, 1, 12)

epoch = 5
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=epoch,validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

in_ = np.array([[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]]).reshape(1,3,12) 
        
print(in_.shape)
out_ = model.predict(in_)
print(out_)
```

Comment: please show x.shape, y.shape before calling `fit()`

Comment: I updated the article.

Comment: try using standard adam learning rate 1e-5

Comment: @Andrey thank you for your advice , I tested many pattern of Adam (0.1~0.000001), but not so much changed. updated articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here you have one major problem, you are trying to do **regression** whereas your problem is pure **classification**.

What you need to do in this part of the code :

```py
def makeModel(input_len,n_in):
    n_hidden = 512
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden, input_shape=(input_len, n_in), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(n_hidden, activation="relu")) 
    model.add(Dense(n_in, activation="relu"))
    opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Change the last layer to a sigmoid activation (output between 0 and 1, like in your case)

```py
model.add(Dense(n_in, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Change the loss to a binary crossentropy

```py
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

By using relu you're trying to map value to an infinite function, which make the learning complicated I would say.

Also, squeeze the Y using

```py
history = model.fit(x, np.squeeze(y), epochs=epoch,validation_data=(x_val, np.squeeze(y_val)))
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but your explanation is quite clear and my problem is solved!!!